# Are SQL queries bottle necking my process?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, rabbitmq

I am using rabbitmq to send a newsletter, which requires a high number of sql queries to be ran simultaneously so it can be built and sent. I am looking to speed up the process so I am looking for the bottleneck, as I make improvements to rabbitmq and it is not speeding up the process I assume it has something to do with the sql database. Is there a limit to how many bytes can be sent. I am using phpmyadmin and I can see bytes received are maybe 5 times that of the bytes sent.

Comment: It's impossible for us to tell you without more information. No, there's no theoretical limit to how many bytes you can send to MySQL - but there's a practical limit (network bandwidth, for instance) which is highly context-dependent.
Have you tried one of these tools to see what's going on in your database? https://www.tecmint.com/mysql-performance-monitoring/

Comment: If I were to guess, SQL queries are indeed what slows your emails down. But not because of some restriction on sent bytes. It's the queries themselves. Each query needs to be sent, executed on the DB server, results need to be sent back and evaluated. All this takes time, especially if your DB server is overwhelmed.